# Python convert multiple single dictionaries into one dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

So I have this dictionary dict that outputs below. It is a variable with multiple dictionaries.

```
 x = {'col1': 1} {'col2': 10}
```

I'd like to know how can I convert it into the dictionary dict and have the output be

```
{'col' 1:1, 'col2':10}
```

Comment: `d1.update(d2)`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26853961/966660

Comment: What is a "variable with multiple dictionaries"? (An iterable (e.g. a list) of dictionaries, maybe? What's the result of running `type(x)`?)